# Calculation of direction between two geographical points

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, logarithms, python

I am trying to capture the relative position (bearing) from one geographical point to another.

I found an online [tool](https://www.sunearthtools.com/tools/distance.php) which does exactly what I am looking for but for some reason I am not able to translate the same logic in simple python function.

The formula being used is as follows (apologies, I am new here and not sure how to covert this into proper math format so I am inserting the screenshot):
[image: formula]

I have tried to translate this into python code as per my understanding but my output is nowhere close to the actual output.

Python code:

```
import math

def calc_bearing(pointA, pointB):
    latA = pointA[0]
    latB = pointB[0]
    lonA = pointA[1]
    lonB = pointB[1]

    delta_ratio = math.log(math.tan(latB / 2 + math.pi / 4) / math.tan(latA / 2 + math.pi / 4))
    delta_lon = abs(lonA - lonB)

    if delta_lon > 180:
        delta_lon = delta_lon % 180
    bearing = math.atan2(delta_lon, delta_ratio)
    return bearing
```

Two geo points for testing, in decimal coordinates:

> g_point1 = (51.51154, -0.0029163)

> g_point2 = (35.6709056, 139.7577372)

Expected output is:

> 98.97 ° degrees

The natural log is also failing since the value is in negative. I am new to trigonometry and geo data plotting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The input coordinate should be converted in radians

Comment: Has MSE become a debug site now?

Comment: Have you actually tried **using** that site? It doesn't work. The site is garbage and its documentation is garbage. Delete the bookmark and find something better.

Comment: One very important question: do you want the direction of the **rhumb line** from A to B or the direction of the **great circle** from A to B? These are two completely different formulas.

Comment: @DavidK I understand. The interface is not the best. I have been trying to find the solution for past few days. If you ignore the interface, it actually provides the right direction from one point to another. This is the closest I have come to find a solution for capturing the direction.

Comment: No, the formula is wrong, at least how it handles longitude.  If $\Delta$lon is 300 then mod 180 gives you 120 while the correct answer is actually -60. https://planetcalc.com/713/ handles longitude correctly (also handles the polar flattening of the Earth, but you can ignore that part).

Comment: @DavidK I have just started exploring this in past few days. My intuition is that if you have 3 points on a map, New York, London and Osaka. London being my starting point, Osaka would be 98.97 degrees and New York would be 258.09 degrees. It is more like a compass view on a flat map.

Comment: If the map you're looking at is a Mercator projection then a straight line on the map will be a rhumb line on the Earth. If you were looking at a different map you might get different answers; for example https://etc.usf.edu/maps/pages/10900/10912/10912.htm would have a course near 30 degrees to Osaka and more than 270 degrees to New York. Note that if you were flying an airliner between those cities, the course on the second map would be much closer to the course in your flight plan than the rhumb-line course would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're using degrees to measure angles, but the trig functions are defined for radian measure, so you just need a small adjustment as I show below. I think you can also omit the `if` statement and just use `delta_lon %= math.pi`, thanks @enzotip for correcting my mistake regarding the conversion.

```
import math

def calc_bearing(pointA, pointB):
    deg2rad = math.pi / 180
    latA = pointA[0] * deg2rad 
    latB = pointB[0] * deg2rad 
    lonA = pointA[1] * deg2rad 
    lonB = pointB[1] * deg2rad 

    delta_ratio = math.log(math.tan(latB/ 2 + math.pi / 4) / math.tan(latA/ 2 + math.pi / 4))
    delta_lon = abs(lonA - lonB)

    delta_lon %= math.pi
    bearing = math.atan2(delta_lon, delta_ratio)/deg2rad
    return bearing


g_point1 = (51.51154, -0.0029163)
g_point2 = (35.6709056, 139.7577372)

print(calc_bearing(g_point1, g_point2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHdboMgGIbPuYrvZAlsVgGLziY70NtYFkOrsyYWDGUHu3pHmRi6lQMweX98Ppi/7VmrfFnGy6yNhYu0Z4S6/hNOcjq1x16aUQ141qOydQL@bMgBgVtdP3AjO3jzqXQeIQP2Sr02SVs74Tf3Tj/gebMHvQl680jXKsqzR3qUv9dXuMnK1kg76gA46QH7DysVvgFkwOElgt8Tt8WO@r@DRO0OwnXL4xV73J2nIuiP42m7Hy@sVxqgpPsVx5s7icFJts7kg6a3X0aFPEJoaP34zFVhwVLBmNgnsKMppbxiRU6Cg98cuUiLklZUFAmwvEpLUZZ5yR3u7PosvnvvUJ1AqHCDL8sP)

Comment: Or even better, instead of `delta_lon=delta_lon%180` you can just do `delta_lon%=180`. They do the same thing but the latter requires less typing.

Comment: `delta_lon` has been converted in radians, so the operation is wrong

Comment: @enzotlib That is an easy fix. Just convert $180^\circ$ to radians like so: $\pi$. Then do `delta_lon%=math.pi`.

Comment: the % operator also works for non integer arguments? Just asking

Comment: @enzotib Yes. I tried it before commenting just in case it didn't work.

Comment: The formula handles longitude incorrectly in degrees or radians. The course from 30N 90E to 20S 90E is not the same as the course from 30N 90E to 20S 90W.

Comment: This does not seem right. The g_point1 was London and g_point2 was Osaka in testing and the output came correct. But when I changed my g_point2 from Osaka to New York (40.748692, -73.985643). Now the direction from London to New York should be 258.09 degrees but it is coming up as 101.91.

Comment: @enzotib Thanks for pointing it out, I corrected it!

Comment: @Mohi Here we can just answer the question you asked: about the python implementation of the formulas you have provided. If you want to ask about the *validity* of these formulas I recommend posting a new question! (also note that $258.09+101.91=360$, so there is probably a sign mistake in the formulas somewhere)

Comment: This being a math site, I would think that incorrect math in someone's software specification would be worthy of comment. But then I would think that even on stackoverflow, so maybe it's just me.